# Setting up kvoptions with a setup command

Tags: package-writing, package-options, kvoptions

The `hyperref` package (for example) provides a `\hypersetup` command where key-value options can be provided as an alternative to `\usepackage[key=value]{hyperref}`.

I'm trying to do the same, using `kvoptions`, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

As far as I understand it, in my `.sty` file I should be able to say

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}
\newcommand*{\Xsetup}[1]{\setkeys{X}{#1}}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=X, prefix=X@}
\DeclareStringOption[default]{key}
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*
```

and then in my `.tex` file say `\Xsetup{key=value}`. This would provide the `\X@key` macro inside the `.sty` file.

Unfortunately, `\X@key` is set to `default` instead of `value` when I do this.

### MWE

#### `kvtest.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvtest}
\Xsetup{key=value}
\begin{document}
    hi
\end{document}
```

#### `kvtest.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{kvtest}[2018/05/17]

\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}

\newcommand*{\Xsetup}[1]{\setkeys{X}{#1}}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=X, prefix=X@}
\DeclareStringOption[default]{key}
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*

\show\X@key
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make a minimal, but compilable example that we could test (with documentclass and the document environment). Maybe you can reduce your package snippet to document commands, otherwise you may include it with `filecontents`.

Comment: @TeXnician I just added a complete MWE. I'm not sure it's possible to merge the package and document in this case, but hopefully it's simple enough.

Comment: Works for me (just tested). The value of key is value.

Comment: @TeXnician thanks for compiling it! That is not what I was expecting. I'm on pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18, kpathsea version 6.2.3 and compiling with `pdflatex kvtest.tex`. In my log I see > `\X@key=macro: ->default.` Very strange that it would work on your machine and not mine.

Comment: Just tried it on a machine with pdflatex 1.40.17, kpathsea 6.2.2 with the same result.

Comment: I guess the compiler version does not matter here (I have the latest TL 2018 with 1.40.19), maybe your kvoptions is outdated. Try updating your packages.

Comment: It turns out that my expectation that the values would be available for other functions in the preamble was the problem. For example, it doesn't seem possible to use `\X@key` as an argument to the package's `hypersetup`. I can live with that, though. Thanks for your help.